# Magento2 Error: Attribute with attributeCode "X" does not exist

Tags: magento2, error, product-attribute

I have created a new attribute for products and added that to the default attribute set. When I then click to navigate to Products > Catalog so that I can implement the attribute, I got the following error:

> Attribute with attributeCode "X" does not exist.

Any suggestions on how to resolve that?

Comment: Clear cache, run indexers and, if still this didn't help try running code compilation (setup:di:compile).

Answer (score 1):

1. Please check the global value. It must be set to 1.
2. Please check the value of is_global in catalog_eav_attribute. It must be 1.
3. Clean the cache and re-index.

Comment: Solution worked perfectly for me today fixing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by clearing out the contents of var/generation.
The issue comes from the attribute factory. Until it's rebuilt it doesn't know your attribute exists

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after creating a new product attribute, all I had to do to resolve it was re-index the product attribute index:

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_attribute
```